# Existing AFPS Time Machine, adding identical drive to create RAID1, possible to do without reformatting?

Tags: disk-utility, diskutil, raid

I did a lot of research already and it seems like this was definitely possible before AFPS (see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041013121106176). The command `diskutil appleRAID enable mirror /dev/diskXsX` could be used to group an existing drive into a RAID1, and then you could add the new drive and 'rebuild' the second drive. However, I'm trying this with an AFPS Time Machine drive, and I'm getting `Error: -69819: File system resize support required, such as HFS+ with Journaling enabled`.

Any advice? I don't have another 6TB drive to temporarily offload the Time Machine data to, so I need to figure this out if it's possible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with RAID1 for a backup disk? If it is to mitigate risk of one drive failing, I would tell TM to backup to both drives and let TM alternate between them.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that's what I think I'm gonna have to do now. I just thought it would be more straightforward if I could get it into a RAID1.